# Multiple rows of data from table into JSON array

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have been on this for nearly a full 24 hours now.

I am not a coder and I am not pretending to be, I just have a problem I cannot solve that I'd like your help with :)

I have a database column full of latitude and longitude locations. I want to create a file called points.json which matches the following format:

```
{
  "points": [
    [LAT, LONG],
    [LAT, LONG],
    [LAT, LONG],
    [LAT, LONG],
    [LAT, LONG]
  ]
}
```

Where LAT and LONG are the records from the database (52.93839800000001,-1.1425212999999999)

My current code gets all the locations from the database and outputs on screen one lat/long per row:

```
$sql = "SELECT latlong from requests";
$result = $con->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo $row['latlong'] . "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$con->close();
```

Table structure:

```
|id|user|       latlong          |
----------------------------------
|1|user|52.93839801,-1.1425212999|
```

I just cannot work out to get it into the above format. I have tried a number of different json_encode methods but end up with separate JSON array for each row?

Ultimately I want to generate a file in the above format on the fly containing the location refs saved in the database column/row.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please share the table structure as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try exploding your latlong and push the values to an array.

```
$sql = "SELECT latlong from requests";
$result = $con->query($sql);

$points = array();

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
       $points[] = explode(',', $row['latlong']);

    }
} 

$con->close();

echo json_encode(array('points' => $points));
```

Comment: Personally I would lose the 

} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

so it will return a valid json anytime.

Comment: Hi Bert! Thanks for your answer :) This seems to be what I am trying to do. Although this gives me a white screen with no error.

I will do some digging with it and see how I get on. Thanks again.

Comment: Hi again Bert, that works a treat! Thanks so much for your time. I really do appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a newer version of MySQL, try the following:

```
SELECT JSON_OBJECT(
        'points', JSON_ARRAYAGG(
            JSON_ARRAY(LAT, LONG)
        )
FROM yourTable;
```

If that doesn't help, share your table structure and your database version.
If you want to try on your own, check out [PHP's json_encode()](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_php.asp)

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code :

```
$sql = "SELECT latlong from requests";
$result = $con->query($sql);


$points = array();
$i=0;
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $latlong = explode(",", $row['latlong']);

        $points['points'][$i] = $latlong;
        $i++;
    }
}

print_r((json_encode($points)));
```